# i cannot pass an array parameters to another class

Tags: java

i am suppose to calculate the area of rectangle in rectangle class but i cannot pass the area of rectangle in cube class.The area of cube is to be calculated by adding the area of rectangle 6 times in an array.[the uml diagram looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N7eB.png)

my rectangle class

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length;
    int width;

    Rectangle(String name, String unit, int length, int width) {

        super(name, unit);
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;

    }

    public int getwidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public int getlength() {
        return this.length;
    }

    public void setwidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setlength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public void getInput() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getArea() {
        return this.width * this.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("length:" + this.length + "width:" + this.width);
        System.out.println("area is" + getArea());
    }

    public class Cube extends Shape {

        Rectangle[] r = new Rectangle[6];

        Boolean solid;
        String color;

        Cube(String name, String unit, Boolean solid, String color) {
            super(name, unit);
            this.solid = solid;
            this.color = color;

        }

        @Override
        public int getArea() {
            int sum = 0;
            r[0] = new Rectangle("Rectangle", "Unit1", 10, 20);
            r[1] = new Rectangle("Rectangle", "Unit2", 10, 20);
            r[2] = new Rectangle("Rectangle", "Unit3", 10, 20);
            r[3] = new Rectangle("Rectangle", "Unit4", 10, 20);
            r[4] = new Rectangle("Rectangle", "Unit5", 10, 20);
            r[5] = new Rectangle("Rectangle", "Unit6", 10, 20);
            for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                sum = sum + r[i];

            }
            return sum;

        }

        @Override
        public void getInput() {

        }

        @Override
        public void display() {
            super.display();
            System.out.println("color:" + this.color + "solid:" + this.solid);
            System.out.println("sum of cube" + getArea());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you are asking. You need to show the code of the `Cube` class where you are passing an array parameter.

Comment: @arfa What do you mean by `but i cannot pass the area of rectangle in cube class.` ?

Comment: it might be clear if u can have a look at the uml diagram link

Comment: Are you getting an error? It looks like you're doing some manual work in the `getArea()` method in your Cube class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code from

`sum= sum+r[i];`

to this

`sum = sum + r[i].getArea();`

Basically you have made an array of `Rectangle`. If you want to get the `width`, `length` or `area` you have to use the getters of your object to get an `int` back for your `sum`.